# using shared preferences to store username and diplay username in fragment class

Tags: android, authentication, android-fragments, fragment, sharedpreferences

My application has a login screen which sends the user to a activity fragment, I would to know how to use shared preferences So That I can store the username the user inputs in the login activity, and call the data stored on the other other fragment, so The username is always displayed on every other fragment activity.

I could pass an intent which stores the user input from the login class and pass it to all the fragment. But my application works like this a user only needs to log in once the next time the is closed it will bypass the login, and the intent will pass  null has no input is passed.
I tried using using shared preference but it returns a nullPointer`lblName.setText(sharedpreferences.getString(name, ""));`
  in myhomFragment  class

where I store the data from login class:

```
public static final String MyPREFERENCES = "MyPrefs";
public static final String name = "nameKey";
public static final String pass = "passwordKey";
SharedPreferences sharedpreferences;

@Override
public void onCreate(Bundle savedInstanceState) {
    super.onCreate(savedInstanceState);
    setContentView(R.layout.login);

    // Importing all assets like buttons, text fields
    inputUser = (EditText) findViewById(R.id.loginUser);
    inputPassword = (EditText) findViewById(R.id.loginPassword);
    btnLogin = (Button) findViewById(R.id.btnLogin);
    btnLinkToRegister = (Button) findViewById(R.id.btnLinkToRegisterScreen);
    loginErrorMsg = (TextView) findViewById(R.id.login_error);

    // Login button Click Event
    btnLogin.setOnClickListener(new View.OnClickListener() {

        @Override
        public void onClick(View view) {

            // Get username, password from EditText
            //String username = inputUser.getText().toString();
            //String password = inputPassword.getText().toString();
            //
            Editor editor = sharedpreferences.edit();
            String u = inputUser.getText().toString();
            String p = inputPassword.getText().toString();
            editor.putString(name, u);
            editor.putString(pass, p);
            editor.commit();
            Intent i = new Intent(getApplicationContext(),
                    MainActivity2.class);
            startActivity(i);
            new ConnectDb().execute();

        }

    });

    // Link to Register Screen
    btnLinkToRegister.setOnClickListener(new View.OnClickListener() {

        public void onClick(View view) {
            Intent i = new Intent(getApplicationContext(),
                    RegisterActivity.class);
            startActivity(i);
            finish();
        }
    });
}

//
@Override
protected void onResume() {
    sharedpreferences = getSharedPreferences(MyPREFERENCES,
            Context.MODE_PRIVATE);
    if (sharedpreferences.contains(name)) {
        if (sharedpreferences.contains(pass)) {
            Intent i = new Intent(getApplicationContext(),
                    MainActivity2.class);

            startActivity(i);
        }
    }
    super.onResume();
}
```

homeFragment class where I want the username to appear in a texView (I want to be able to display the user logged in on every fragments).

```
public static final String MyPREFERENCES = "MyPrefs";
public static final String name = "nameKey";
public static final String pass = "passwordKey";
TextView lblName;

AlertDialogManager alert = new AlertDialogManager();
// Session Manager Class
SharedPreferences sharedpreferences;

public HomeFragment() {
}

@Override
public View onCreateView(LayoutInflater inflater, ViewGroup container,
        Bundle savedInstanceState) {

    sharedpreferences = getActivity().getSharedPreferences(MyPREFERENCES,
            Context.MODE_PRIVATE);

    if (sharedpreferences.contains(name)) {
        lblName.setText(sharedpreferences.getString(name, ""));

    }
```

Comment: Do not reveal your URL links publicly as you did in `loginURL`. It can be misused by others..

Comment: @Mr_and_Mrs_D I've formatted the code and edited my question

Comment: Improved but not perfect still - avoid blank lines unless needed and correct your typos :)

Comment: Did you find an answer ?

Answer (score 0):

Delete the `public HomeFragment() { }` - and in general avoid constructors in fragments and activities. You are getting the NPE due to your not initializing the `lblName` variable.

Comment: I am new to android development How do I initialise a textView. I know   to initialise a string u give it a value like putting it in a loop for example:`for( int i=0; i<user.size();i++){`
But how should i initialise a textview? please

Comment: @BrandonMilambo: exactly as you initialize `loginErrorMsg = (TextView) findViewById(R.id.login_error);` (?)

Comment: I have done that I created a textview called lblName; at the top and  `lblName = (TextView) rootView.findViewById(R.id.lblName);` in my code

Comment: At the top ? You mean in the fields ? You must do it onAttachView or in onCreate